# Elden Ring Controller Problems

Tags: elden-ring

Hey guys, I've been trying to finish my play through of Elden Ring for months now, but the Game on Steam one day stopped me from playing with my controller, and now recently I can't play with mouse and keyboard. 
 
For context, I play with a Series X controller; I play on Steam; I've reinstalled Elden Ring twice; I have used probably 30 different official and community based configuration files from Steam; I have tried 3 different controllers; I have unplugged all peripherals except the controller; when I try using keyboard and mouse, it thinks I AM using a controller, and all the inputs are wrong, which means I can't play it. I've only had one of Steam's config Files to work, It's an unofficial one, but it only lets me navigate the menu, and not play the game. 
 I'm really at a loss here. I was hoping someone on this forum could help me out, since I would really like to finish the game. I'm on the Mountaintop of the Giants.